# jQuery/JS: Read text file from Server synchronously

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm extending a kinda big existing application. At one place I have to read data from a text file (or process a php echo). The problem is that I need synchronous behaviour.

I've done some reading and found two possible solutions which I both can't use (well).

The first is to use `async:false` in an ajax call. But as far as I understood, this won't be supported anymore soon (the fact that it may freeze the end users browser also isn't too nice).

The second option I found is to use `callbacks`. I also can't really use those as I would have to change, like, a really big part of the application to make it work.

Is there any other possibility to solve that problem? How I provide the text is up to me, so maybe changing something here may help?

Answer (score 0):

AJAX stands for **Asynchronous** Javascript and XML. So, what's the point of making an AJAX call in the first place if you have to make it synchronous? If you need a synchronous call, you should handle it PHP side and return your data already processed to HTML.